# Removing elements from sublists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A` containing many sublists. I want to remove specific element from each sublist. For example, remove element `0` from `A[0]`, remove element `1` from `A[1]` and so on. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
A=[[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

for i in range(0,len(A)): 
    A[i].remove(A[i]==i)
print(A)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A[i].remove(A[i]==i)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The expected output is

```
[[2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 6], [0, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: `A[i]==i` this will reproduce only `0` and `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove an item `i` but not the condition `A[i]==i`:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i].remove(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to enumerate your list. Also make sure that the value you're trying to remove actually exists. Use try/except to handle that scenario

```
A = [[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

for i, e in enumerate(A):
    try:
        e.remove(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(A)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 6], [0, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]]
```